# ringtones volume increase Lumia 640xl

Tags: volume

The built in volume scale is 10/10 and barely audible in any noise environment. How can I work around this for greater volume. For instance this same phone has a music volume scale of 30/30, a much louder volume.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry. There is no way you can get around this.

If there's an important call you're waiting for and the environment is noisy, you can plug in your earphones.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, i windows phone maximum is 30.

for ringTone and notification Maximum : 10/10

for music player : 30/30

i understand your needs. windows phone defaults tone available and its more louder.
or use ringtone maker app, because compare with music player its more louder.

if not only once choice vibrate.

for more find this site:  https://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/settings-and-personalization/ringtones-sounds-and-volume

Answer (score -1):

No. You can't and doens't do it **without interop**.
Search in the <kbd>XDA-Developers</kbd> forum for a tool for registry editor, then good hacking!